# ¿Se usa/entiende la expresión "cascarón de huevo" más allá de Andalucía?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, diferencias-regionales, solicitud-de-modismo

Acá por el sur de España usamos la expresión ***cascarón de huevo*** para designar a aquellas personas a las que, por el motivo que sea (bien la edad, bien la salud, bien la inexperiencia), no se les deben aplicar las reglas.

Por ejemplo: vamos a jugar al pillar o al escondite, y para integrar a los niños pequeños que no tienen la velocidad, agilidad o astucia suficiente, se les dice que son *cascarón de huevo*, y entonces no se les aplican las normas. Pueden jugar como uno más, pero si se les atrapa o encuentra no se la quedan ([DLE](https://dle.rae.es/quedar), acepción 16) el siguiente turno. Por extensión, se puede usar también en ámbitos adultos de forma coloquial, por ejemplo cuando alguien es nuevo y no está enterado de los formalismos de algún grupo de personas ("el último que llega paga") y pide ser cascarón de huevo.

El caso es que acabo de caer en la cuenta de que puede que la expresión no se use más allá de las fronteras de nuestra región. No he encontrado casos ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA, y las búsquedas por Internet arrojan como primeros resultados páginas en las que se habla del significado de la expresión, pero ninguna en la que se use efectivamente.

Así pues:

- ¿Se usa la expresión en el resto de España y del mundo hispanohablante? ¿Se entiende, al menos?
- Si no es así, ¿qué otras expresiones se usan para el mismo concepto?

Comment: Sólo conocía la primera acepción (la de los juegos), pero sólo la he escuchado por el sur de España, no la he oído en el País Vasco. Aquí, la expresión equivalente que se escucha es "ser caballito blanco", pero insisto en que sólo en el ámbito infantil y de juegos.

Comment: "Cascarilla" en Málaga capital, más que "cascarón de huevo". Interesante pregunta.

Comment: No sabría decir donde, pero en alguna provincia española se usa "azucarillo"

Answer (score 1):

Yo es la primera vez que la escucho.

Hay una frase que no es exactamente la misma definición pero está relacionada.

### Pido gancho

Aplicado a los juegos infantiles:

- Decir o gritar "pido gancho" cruzando los dedos índice y mayor, implica que un jugador, en el acto, detiene y/o suspende los efectos y acciones relacionados con cualquier juego del que se esta participando. Es una inmunidad temporal que dura el tiempo que los dedos permanecen cruzados.

Hay referencias mundiales muy divertidas en [este enlace](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pido-gancho-%C2%A1sangre.1234816/), con explicaciones al gesto de los dedos cruzados y relación al origen o adaptación del inglés [King's X](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/King%27s%20X).

Comment: Efectivamente, no es lo mismo. Para la inmunidad temporal en el colegio de mis niños se ha puesto de moda decir "¡V!" (ni idea de por qué). Creo que esa expresión es todavía más localizada que la que propongo en la pregunta, que se refiere a una inmunidad permanente.

Comment: Creo que lo mencionan en el enlace